# GraphQL how to setup query the MongoDB ref collection using Nestjs or type-graphql

Tags: mongodb, graphql, nestjs, typegraphql

I have question about how to use GraphQL to query the ref collection in mongodb.
I have two collections: People and Cat. People will have zero or one cat, and Cat will belongs to one People.

First, I use graphql create a People, then copy the returned People's ID.

Next, I pass that People's ID to CreateCatService to create a cat, so that this created cat is belongs to the previous created people.

Now the problem is I cannot query the ref (nested) collection's data.

```
mutation {
  createCat(
    input: {
      name: "my cat"
      age: 1
      breed: "test"
      people: "5e6edf120e27eb369db9ceaa" <----- People's id
    }
  ) {
    id
    name
    people {
      name <--- return null ???
    }
  }
}
```

If I query the Cat, the nested People is null, it shows err: `"message": "ID cannot represent value: <Buffer 5e 6e df`

```
{
  cats {
    name
    people {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my schema and the code generate typedef.

```
export const PeopleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  cat: {type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: "Cat"}
})
```

```
export const CatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  breed: String,
  people: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'People'}
});
```

```
@ObjectType()
export class PeopleType {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field()
  name: string;

  @Field(type => CatType, { nullable: true })
  cat?: CatType
}
```

```
@ObjectType()
export class CatType {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field()
  readonly name: string;

  @Field(() => Int)
  readonly age: number;

  @Field()
  readonly breed: string;

  @Field(type => PeopleType, {nullable: true})
  readonly people?: PeopleType;
}
```

My CatInput:

```
@InputType()
export class CatInput {
  @Field()
  readonly name: string;

  @Field(() => Int)
  readonly age: number;

  @Field()
  readonly breed: string;

  @Field()
  readonly people: string; // this will be the people's id
}
```

My CreateCatService

```
  async create(createCatDto: CatInput): Promise<Cat> {
    const createdCat = new this.catModel(createCatDto);
    return await createdCat.save();
```

My CatResolver

```
  @Mutation(() => CatType)
  async createCat(@Args('input') input: CatInput) {
    return this.catsService.create(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your resolver has no idea how to resolve people in the ObjectType. You need to create a FieldResolver in your Resolver class.

See: https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/blob/master/docs/resolvers.md#field-resolvers

Basically in your CatResolver you need a method `people` of type FieldResolver, this should inject PeopleType(not certain here: read the article)

```
  @FieldResolver()
  people(@Root() people: People) {
    // then using the people id in root, get the people detail from People.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of changes, I found out the issue is that I didn't populate the sub collection. In the CatResolver, instead of returning `createdCat.save();` I need to do this:

```
    const savedCat = await createdCat.save();
    return await savedCat.populate('people').execPopulate();
```